# How can I zip a list over another list that is nested in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, nested-lists, map-function, algebraic-data-types

so, here's a type definition, just for some context:

```hs
type Name = String
type Coordinates = (Int, Int)
type Pop = Int
type TotalPop = [Pop]
type City = (Name, (Coordinates, TotalPop))
```

And here's a data set:

```hs
testData :: [City]
testData = [("New York City", ((1,1), [5, 4, 3, 2])),
           ("Washingotn DC", ((3,3), [3, 2, 1, 1])),
           ("Los Angeles", ((2,2), [7, 7, 7, 5]))]
```

So, I'm trying to make a function (`addAllPops`) to edit `TotalPop` of all `City`'s in `[City]` with a new entry at the start of `TotalPop`. I want it to work in such a way that in the example below, the input `addNewPop testData [6, 4, 8]` would change them to:

```hs
"New York City", ((1,1), [6, 5, 4, 3, 2],
"Washingotn DC", ((3,3), [4, 3, 2, 1, 1],
"Los Angeles", ((2,2), [8, 7, 7, 7, 5]
```

The function to change just one single city's population is here, along with my attempt for the whole, my biggest issue is entirely around collapsing the two lists into one.

```hs
addAllPops :: [City] -> [Int] -> [City]
addAllPops [(w, ((x,y), z))] pops = [map uncurry addPop (zip pops z)]

addPop :: City -> Int -> City
addPop (w, ((x,y), z)) p = (w, ((x,y), p:z))
```

I've been stuck on this for an embarassingly long amount of time, any and all assistance is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your instinct to start with `addPop` working one at a time is correct.  Now look at the type signature of `zipWith`:

```
zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
```

It takes a function which operates pointwise and lifts it to operate on two lists in parallel.  So you `zipWith` the cities and the list of new elements, using `addPop` to combine them pointwise:

```
addAllPops :: [City] -> [Int] -> [City]
addAllPops cities newPops = zipWith addPop cities newPops
```

We can eta-contract this definition to arrive at the surprisingly simple

```
addAllPops = zipWith addPop
```

You could have done this with `zip` and `map` also, but it's just more plumbing.